# How to handle large numbers in Java?

Tags: java

My first game allows a user to earn a large amount of money, that I am storing as a simple INT. The problem is of course is that max INT is 2 billion or so. I've been stuck on this problem for over a year, embarrassingly.

Think clicker/idle type games where the numbers get huge but are suffixed with "k"(thousands), "M"(millions), "B"(billions) etc so this problem can be avoided completely since they probably only show max 99999 or so.

I could go ahead and change my game to use a system like this, but my question is:

How can I perform proper calculations?
If I have some vars named like `intThousands` `intMillions` to solve the above problem, how could I perform math on them since the result could be above the 2 billion max? First thought is, I check if the result is more than 2 billion, and if so, start using `intBillions` for example. But that would still mean the result is more than 2 billion and thus throws max int error.

Maybe something like:

```
if (intResult >= Int32.MaxValue) {
        // let's say intResult = 20,900,000,000

        get the remainder and split it up:
        intBillions = 20;
        intMillions = 900;
        intThousands = 0;
        intHundreds = 0;
        intOnes = 0;    
}
```

Then someone perform calcs and transform back and forth between full numbers as one int and combining a few...

This is a logic problem that I cannot get past unfortunately. I would love to hear your thoughts on a solution, what I am doing wrong, or most likely how I am thinking about this problem wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: Look into [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: check this out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: No, look into `BigDecimal` for money.

Comment: You could just use a `long` (*64 bit integer*) or `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

```
BigInteger playerMoney = new BigInteger("100000000000000000");
BigInteger earnedMoreMoney = new BigInteger("4200000000000");
BigInteger totalMoney = playerMoney.add(earnedMoreMoney);
System.out.println(totalMoney);
```

Output:

```
100004200000000000
```

The formatting with `k`, `M` etc. should be a completely separate issue. First make sure that you can count every cent precisely, then think about how to write down the number in a readable way. Separate the model from the presentation/view!